# Connecting points to form triangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry

$3n$ points are drawn on a flat piece of paper, such that no $3$ points lie on a straight line. Is it always possible to connect triples of points with straight lines, such that you form $n$ triangles and no two triangles intersect or touch each other?

Comment: Trivially no if all 3n points are on a line. Probably you mean that no three points are on a single line?

Comment: @Bubbler yes i agree, having 9 points in a 3x3 grid , its not possible to connect pairs of points to form N triangles. Plus I fail to understand what the OP means by pairs points while referring to 3 sets of points.

Comment: ah sorry, forgot about collinear points. Will update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it possible?

> Yes it is always possible.

Why?

> Order your points by x-coordinate (and by y for those with equal x  - if any).
>  Take three points at a time from the ordered list to form each triangle.
>  The first triangle obviously won't intersect any other.
>  For each subsequent triple, its points are entirely to the right of all triangles created so far (or at least as far right and above - for the equal x case), so edges between them are guaranteed to not intersect existing triangles.

Comment: I think you could also rot13(ebgngr gur cynar (ol rcfvyba) fb gung ab gjb cbvagf unir gur fnzr l-inyhr) to make the rest of the argument a little slicker